# How to find an asymptote of a logarithmic curve

Tags: plotting

An exponential decay curve has been plotted asymptoting at approximately x=30 (correct for what I am looking at)

How can I find the exact value from the curve? I was hoping to be able to use something similar to the `FindMinimum` function, or draw a line along the asymptote and find the intersection with the x-axis.

This is the function used to plot the curve:

```
    Plot[((5/Log[2])*Log[(80046.8 - ((0.79) (101325 + (1030*9.81*d))))/((313545. + 2.17341d) - ((0.79) (101325 + (1030*9.81*d))))]), {d, 0, 60}, AxesLabel -> {Depth - m, Time - mins}]
```

Comment: This site is for questions about the software *Mathematica*. Did you mean to ask this here, or at [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Yes, the curve has been plotted on mathematica

Comment: Okay, could you give the function that generates this decay curve you speak of?

Comment: Surely you can see that your question is underspecified. *How* and *what* do you plot? Yes, an exponential curve; but what do you do? `Plot[1+Exp[-x/5],{x,0,50}]`? something else? Try to be specific. Pretend that you don't know what you are doing; would you understand your explanation? If not, neither will we...

Comment: Sorry, this is the first time I have used this website. I have have put my function in the question..

Comment: A hint: Apply `Rationalize[]` to your function first, and then feed this to `Limit[]`: `Limit[(* your function *), d -> ∞]`

Comment: Try `Series[(* your function *), {d, ∞, 2}]`.

Comment: A quick and dirty approach works well here: change the plot range to end at $10^{15}$, say.  Read the answer off the y-axis (to eight decimal places).  @Silvia Nice idea--but note that you only need to know the series through order $0$!

Comment: @whuber just in case it approach the limit with some higher order. And I like to watch a series with really *series* of terms :)

Answer (score 2):

The vertical asymptote is caused by the denominator of the Log function going through zero. Therefore, find the value of $d$ such that your denominator is zero.

```
Solve[(313545. + 2.17341 d - 0.79 (101325 + 1030*9.81*d)) == 0, d
```

The result is 29.259612511.